# Dynamical D3 Collapsible Tree Layout with wicket

Tags: java, d3.js, wicket

I just discovered the [D3 Collapsible Tree Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083), and i must say, it's pretty amazing. So I'm a newbie in it so please be patient.

I have this project which I must do with Wicket (version 6.8.0). **My problem** is that I want to render a list (with D3 Collapsible Tree Layout) dynamically. I explain:

I have a form which takes a file identifier and depending on it, will display a list. So the list must be rendered dynamically. I know how to do this with the ListView object in Wicket but when it comes to the D3 Collapsible Tree Layout, it's written in javascript so I have no idea how to do this.
Usually, I'll do like this:

```
<ul>
   <span wicket:id="myObject">
      <li>something
          <ul>
               <li><strong>Date</strong>
                   <span wicket:id="date"></span>
               </li>
               <li><strong>Name</strong>
                   <span wicket:id="name"></span>
               </li>
          </ul> 
      </li>
   </span>
</ul>
```

Then in the Java code: `ListView myObject = new ListView("myObject", myModel) {...}`

I hope I made myself clear about my problem.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Hey, that js tree viewer is pretty slick.  I am not familiar with that tree specifically, but if you know how to populate the tree data in javascript you could try `target.prependJavaScript("your javascript here");` or `target.appendJavaScript("your javascript here");`.  I'm not sure if you can just call `target.add(javascriptContainer);` to refresh it or if you will have to do more...  Good luck!

Comment: For this you need to use AJAX requests in Javascript (e.g. using `d3.json`) to get the data dynamically as nodes are expanded. If you have no experience with Javascript and AJAX I strongly suggest working through a few tutorials before you embark on this, likewise for D3.